# Django ASGI Deployment on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, channel, asgi

I want a clear cut explanation of how should I deploy Django 3.x and channels 2.x on Heroku.
 my asgi.py file

```
import os
import django
from channels.routing import get_default_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mainProj.settings')

django.setup()

application = get_default_application()
```

also,

```
import channels.asgi
```

and

```
channel_layer = channels.asgi.get_channel_layer()
```

**returns an error saying no module named channels.asgi**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you want to get_channel_layer() from other views or function/methods?

should be import like this:

```
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer

channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
```